# How to access a object programatically created in android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

**What I have done**::

I created three checkboxes programatically and assigned id's and params for it

**What i am trying to do**::

- How to set the second checkbox text to newvalue say`"newcheckbox"`
- I am not able to understand how this Programatic thing works

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        CheckBox chkBox;
        LinearLayout CheckBoxContainer;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            CheckBoxContainer=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Container);


            for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
                chkBox= new CheckBox(this);
                chkBox.setId(i);
                chkBox.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                chkBox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);

                chkBox.setText("checkbox");
                CheckBoxContainer.addView(chkBox);
            }



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
   String[] arr_str = {"checkbox 1","checkbox 2","checkbox 3"};

   for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
         chkBox= new CheckBox(this);
         chkBox.setId(i);
         chkBox.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         chkBox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);

         chkBox.setText(arr_str[i]);
         CheckBoxContainer.addView(chkBox);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get and edit the checkbox afterwards like this:

```
chkBox = (CheckBox) CheckBoxContainer.findViewById(1);
chkBox.setText("hello");
```

1 is the id you assigned to 2nd checkbox.